# What is this plant with red/green leaves and yellow flowers?

Tags: identification

I noticed this plant at an open house, and this particular specimen was one of the smaller ones there. I'm wondering if I can plant one of these in a partially shaded spot next to the walkway.

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Canna...[Canna tropical](http://www.brecks.com/images/500/66916.jpg)  Pretty hardy plant that dies back in winter unless you live in the tropics or subtropics. Cut those flowers off before they start wilting!  You'll be able to convince your plant to keep producing flowers/seeds.

Comment: Thanks. I'm in Southern California / USDA hardiness zone 10a, so I'm hoping they would be fine in the winter...

Comment: This must be a new home?  I don't think you'll have to worry about winter die back!!  Must be nice...feel free to cut out leaves and cut off flowers!

Comment: Well, that plant isn't mine, but it seems like one I should consider. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great specimen plant...can't go wrong!